# Rails: How to test with readonly database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, unit-testing, readonly

I am writting an application to display some data from a readonly database. 
Now I want to use TestCases to test the application. The database ist quite big and it is really much effort to write or generate good test data for each table.

Is there any possibility in Rails to run automated tests with a database with readonly access?

Comment: basically test cases use different database and they also execute migration and seeds so read only database will not work over here

Comment: Is there any possiblity to change this basic configuration?

Comment: Every time when you run test cases it will use test database and will recreate that database.